# What does it mean to be "standardised", and why is Haskell it?

Tags: haskell, standards

Wikipedia [claims](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haskell_%28programming_language%29) that Haskell is "standardised", but the Haskell standard is not ratified by an internationally recognised standards body such as ISO; not even by a national body such as BSI or ANSI.

So what really are the criteria for a programming language to be labelled "standardised"? Does it just need to have [a specification published on a website somewhere](http://www.haskell.org/definition/)?

Comment: This is a really great question, but you should be asking it at http://programmers.stackexchange.com. It's exactly the subject-matter for that site.

Comment: I think it's meant here in an informal way to refer to the fact that it has been designed by a committee, and via reaching consensus on design questions among the committee members, and is specified by a document that is independent of a particular implementation. Even though the standard has not been ratified, it's still a standard. You can use it to determine in how far a given implementation is compliant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've answered your own question. A standardised language is one which is defined by some specification, be it a document or a 'reference implementation' in a language that is itself standardised and formalized (such as SML). Which body recognizes or approves the standard is not really at issue.

This is as opposed to an implementation-defined language, such as Perl or PHP, where what the language does is defined simply by what some particular "flagship" implementation of the language does.

So we can say a certain C compiler doesn't actually compile C properly, because it does not obey the standard. Meanwhile, we can't say that CPython does not interpret Python properly, because what it does *is* what Python does, by definition.

Haskell is defined by the Haskell Report, the latest version of which is Haskell 2010: http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/

This report is crafted by a committee, voted on, and ratified. Furthermore, there historically have been and remain multiple Haskell compilers and interpreters which either conform to the report, or *almost* conform to the report, with documented exceptions.

Code written to the standard should be portable across compilers, and when divergences are found between compilers and the report (other than 'expected' ones), then it is usual that either the compiler or report will be changed to conform.

Comment: I would disagree that a reference implementation is sufficient to be considered standardised.  A specification is necessary to allow for interoperability.

Comment: I think it depends. I really went back-and-forth on this, but, e.g., the (abandoned) ECMAScript 4 reference implementation was done in SML. Just like not every document is a specification, not every implementation is a standards-quality reference implementation. But if done right, I think it can be a superior approach. see, e.g., this discussion: http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/1784